# making apache lenya work with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, apache

I am new to java ... As per the documentation of apache lenya It doesnot use db by default but it can be configured to use db.. can anyone suggest a manual for configuring apache lenya to work with mysql....?

Comment: Which version of lenya are you using? 1.2.x or 2.0.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the below link, it might provide you a bit insights.

[Click Here](http://markmail.org/message/35rz7mho33y5bwva#query%3a+page:1+mid:35rz7mho33y5bwva+state%3aresults)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any installations going against a database. There certainly isn't anything in 2.0.3 that would make this easy to do, and would require a fairly extensive rewrite. There may be ways of accomplishing whatever it is that you're after without using a database.